# znapzendzetup create fails indicating it can't find SRC filesystem being created

Tags: znapzend

Why does znapzendzetup create fail indicating it can't find SRC filesystem being created

```
sudo znapzendzetup create --tsformat='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' SRC '1min=>10min,5min=>20min' /mnt/test/src DST '5min=>1year' /mnt/test/bak

ERROR: filesystem /mnt/test/src does not exist
```

NOTE: This Question is copied from the github bug tracker since many people seem to confuse zfs fileset names with mount points.

Comment: You know we have a policy about spam right? You're asking 'questions' and answering them about your own product - this really isn't on, it's just self-promotion!

Comment: znapzend is free and opensource ... I put this question in because it is one that we got on github as a bug report and also on irc ... I thought adding entries with FAQs was ok ? No ? https://github.com/oetiker/znapzend/issues/130

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up datasets and mountpoints. ZnapZend deals with zfs datasets.

`/mnt/test/src` is a mountpoint

you have to specify the zfs dataset, not the mountpoint.

a dataset normally starts with the name of a pool and no slash: `pool/apps/dummy`

Comment: I've never heard of this tool. What does it do, Tobi? Can I monitor it with Orca? ;)

Comment: see http://www.znapzend.org really need a znapzend tag :)

Comment: Answering the prayers of many who've been waiting for such a thing... No tag for you yet.